# How can I update a remote branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Using SourceTree, I reset my local repository to a previous commit. I then used GitBash to do a `gitk --date-order` to see the commits in the Bare repository which I push to in order to update that to the same previous commit. I did this using `git update-ref HEAD [SHA ID]`. Both the Bare repository and the one I originally reset have only one branch.

Now I want to update my remote repository back to that previous commit. I am unclear on how to use the `git remote` commands to do the exact same thing. The wrinkle being that I have two remote branches: development and master. I only pushed those changes I wanted to reset to the development branch (master has not been merged yet).

Can anyone show me the commands to update my remote development branch correctly?

Comment: You want to know how to update a remote branch to be the same as your local branch?

Comment: Force push your localbranch to your remote. `git push $development $localbranch:$remotebranch -f`

Comment: @BryceDrew, will this effectively delete the commits I want to get rid of? And if so do I replace "$development $localbranch:$remotebrach" with the names of my branches? So it looks like `git push $development $development:$development`?

Comment: Yes, but don't do that if you want to keep your co-workers from strangling you. Don't do this normally. If someone is working on their code on top of that history, your new branch won't be compatible with their code. Read [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6204804/6194839), [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6206542/6194839), and [This](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/). You don't want to mess with remote history. Just add a new commit to undo a previous commit's history.

Comment: Those are variables I used because I don't know your branch names, or the location of your remote servers. For me, it could be `git push ~/Desktop/foo foo:master -f`, for you it could be something else.

Comment: @BryceDrew This is a personal repository and not shared with anyone, so no worries there. Sorry to be a bit daft, but I am new to git and I obviously don't know the commands well enough. My local repository is in E:/Code/Code.Website1. The local branch is "development". The remote repository's branch is also "development". So would it be: `git push ~/Code/Code.Website1/development development:development -f`?

Comment: `git remote add development E:Code/Code.Website1` then `git push development -f` Understand that if you have not backed up the development remote, the history will not be preserved, and you won't be able to get that back.

Comment: @BryceDrew That worked. Thanks so much. I'll mark as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git remote add development E:Code/Code.Website1
git push development -f
```

Understand that if you have not backed up the development remote, the history will not be preserved, and you won't be able to get that back.

Understand that you should not be changing your remote history if your remote is accessible by anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar using GitBash and I am adding an answer using TortoiseGit (GUI for newbees) here:
[Force re-basing remote branch with local branch using TortoiseGit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JelTb.png)

Like many mentioned above, do this if only with your "private" repo branch and that means no one will ever throw a chair at you for re-basing the remote "develop" or "feature" branch with your local copy. The other devs who've committed and pushed their week's worth (or more) of work will be ERASED from the branch's history (log).

There will be no way to recover them - of course your co-developers will still have their changes on theirs as their PULL will most likely throw an error as they will be way way ahead of the branch current history or latest commits vs. theirs. Good thing Git is a distributed versioning system.

So, be careful with this power to reverting a remote branch. You are hereby warned. ;)